# Combining wav files programmatically - Python

Tags: python, wav, pydub

I am looking to combine 10 audio samples in various manners (format - wav probably, but this can be changed to any format as they will be pre-recorded).

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sounds = []
sound1 = AudioSegment.from_wav("Dropbox/PIREAD/1.wav")
sound2 = AudioSegment.from_wav("Dropbox/PIREAD/2.wav")
sound3 = AudioSegment.from_wav("Dropbox/PIREAD/3.wav")
sound4 = AudioSegment.from_wav("Dropbox/PIREAD/4.wav")
sound5 = AudioSegment.from_wav("Dropbox/PIREAD/5.wav")
sound6 = AudioSegment.from_wav("Dropbox/PIREAD/6.wav")
sound7 = AudioSegment.from_wav("Dropbox/PIREAD/7.wav")
sound8 = AudioSegment.from_wav("Dropbox/PIREAD/8.wav")
sound9 = AudioSegment.from_wav("Dropbox/PIREAD/9.wav")
sound0 = AudioSegment.from_wav("Dropbox/PIREAD/0.wav")

sounds=[sound1,sound2,sound3,sound4,sound5,sound6,sound7,sound8,sound9,sound0]

combined_sounds = AudioSegment.empty()

for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        combined_sounds += sounds[y]
    
combined_sounds.export("Dropbox/PIREAD/joinedFile.wav", format="wav")
```

This is literally me reading the numbers 0-9 and assembling them into one overall wav file.

It works - but it is slow once the loop is extended x=100, x=1000.

Q: How can I speed things up?

The actual order of the numbers will be read from a text$ - for example "354224848179261915075"  which happens to be the 100th Fibonacci number.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Why are you doing a double loop? If you want 1-10 and then 1-10 again and again 10 times total, then it would be better to just re-add 10-element segment later, rather than go through all 10 files again. (The difference is: going 10^2 times or going 2*10 times)

Comment: See below - was just testing for speed.  DOH!!! should have though BigO before I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions and advice above.  This is the final code I used and link to the resultant video (with ffmpeg visualisation):

```
# Program to display the Fibonacci sequence up to n-th term
from pydub import AudioSegment
    
combined_sounds = ""
sound1 = AudioSegment.from_wav("1_2.wav")
sound2 = AudioSegment.from_wav("2_2.wav")
sound3 = AudioSegment.from_wav("3_2.wav")
sound4 = AudioSegment.from_wav("4_2.wav")
sound5 = AudioSegment.from_wav("5_2.wav")
sound6 = AudioSegment.from_wav("6_2.wav")
sound7 = AudioSegment.from_wav("7_2.wav")
sound8 = AudioSegment.from_wav("8_2.wav")
sound9 = AudioSegment.from_wav("9_2.wav")
sound0 = AudioSegment.from_wav("0_2.wav")



nterms=1000
# first two terms
n1, n2 = 0, 1
count = 0
fib = ""

# check if the number of terms is valid
if nterms <= 0:
    print("Please enter a positive integer")
# if there is only one term, return n1
elif nterms == 1:
    print("Fibonacci sequence upto",nterms,":")
    print(n1)
# generate fibonacci sequence
else:
    print("Fibonacci sequence:")
    while count < nterms:
        #print(n1)
        fib += str(n1)
        nth = n1 + n2
       # update values
        n1 = n2
        n2 = nth
        count += 1
        
i=-36
j=0

fibs = [fib[i:i+1000] for i in range(0, len(fib), 1000)]

seg = 0
for a in fibs:
    if seg == 2:
        break
        
    combined_sounds = AudioSegment.empty()
    seg +=1
    for x in a:
        i,j = -36,0
        s = eval("sound"+str(x))    
        s = s.apply_gain_stereo(i,j)
        combined_sounds += s
        i,j = j,i
        

    combined_sounds.export("joinedFile"+str(seg)+".wav", format="wav")
```

This splits the output into 1000 digit wav files.  The first 1000 Fibonacci terms produces nearly 15Gb of wavs!

Uploaded to YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7Z_HOGqjlE

Thanks all.

Comment: Can I make my own reply the accepted answer - apologies for my lack of SO-fu

Comment: Absolutely. Self-answering is encouraged, self-acceptance is too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's slow because when you loop over `x`, you repeat operations (the loop over `y`) which could be computed before the loop over `x`, then assembled.

Comment: The nested for's are for testing.  What I want to achieve is parse a string - "num = 123456789" and to assemble a spoken representation of this.  The only thing being that the number will be 1000s of characters long.

Comment: So - can iterate over the characters in the num and pull those wav files from a dict? and then assemble them.   Will get on and test.

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you are trying to do: seems like you're trying to create an acoustic representation of the Fibo sequence (neat project!). I believe if you try low numbers, like the first 10 numbers of the sequence, this program should stop pretty quicly. From which step does your program feel slow?

Comment: Exactly this...  In different accents, different languages, different genders etc etc   My for loop was to generate numbers to test -- what I will do is to change this to the actual Fib numbers --- only one loop then to iterate over the digits.

Comment: Beware of how you're computing the Fib sequence, this could be the step that's slowing your program ;)

Comment: Going down the rabbit hole now ;-)   Fib imported from a precomputed list - so should be ok.  It was the for....loops that was killing it -- should have thought it through before I posted.

Comment: If my answer solved your question, you can close your question by accepting the answer

Answer (score 1):

I looked into [`AudioSegment`](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/audio_segment.py) and found potentially useful method for you namely `from_mono_audiosegments` but it is limited to mono sounds and you will need to test if it is faster than `+=` please compare time-wise these options, i.e.

```
import time
from pydub import AudioSegment
sounds = []
sound1 = AudioSegment.from_wav("Dropbox/PIREAD/1.wav")
sound2 = AudioSegment.from_wav("Dropbox/PIREAD/2.wav")
sound3 = AudioSegment.from_wav("Dropbox/PIREAD/3.wav")
sound4 = AudioSegment.from_wav("Dropbox/PIREAD/4.wav")
sound5 = AudioSegment.from_wav("Dropbox/PIREAD/5.wav")
sound6 = AudioSegment.from_wav("Dropbox/PIREAD/6.wav")
sound7 = AudioSegment.from_wav("Dropbox/PIREAD/7.wav")
sound8 = AudioSegment.from_wav("Dropbox/PIREAD/8.wav")
sound9 = AudioSegment.from_wav("Dropbox/PIREAD/9.wav")
sound0 = AudioSegment.from_wav("Dropbox/PIREAD/0.wav")

sounds=[sound1,sound2,sound3,sound4,sound5,sound6,sound7,sound8,sound9,sound0]
# option1 using +=
t1 = time.time()
combined_sounds1 = AudioSegment.empty()
for s in sounds
    combined_sounds1 += s
t2 = time.time()
# end of option1
# option2 using from_mono_audiosegments
t3 = time.time()
combined_sounds2 = AudioSegment.from_mono_audiosegments(*sounds)
t4 = time.time()
# end of option2
print('option1 (seconds):',t2-t1)
print('option2 (seconds):',t4-t3)
```

Comment: Nice - every little helps (speed I mean - the help is greatly appreciated) -- will update with progress.  TY